# Kendo UI Angular 2 Framework - Chart Component error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I have set up a basic Angular 2 application using the following technique: 
***angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html***

I have added the Kendo UI to my application using the following technique:
***www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started***
(using the Quickstart method)

The Kendo UI button displays and works as expected.  So now I would like to add the Kendo UI chart using this technique:
***www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/#installation***

This caused the following error in the console window of my Chrome browser (Version 54.0.2840.71 m) :

> //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-charts 404 (Not Found)
>
> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-charts(…)

Do I need a reference/definition in system.config.js for my chart component?  Not sure as the Kendo UI installation documentation makes no mention of it.  I did see something about this regarding the button though so... Lets add it.

```js
    (function (global) {
      System.config({
        paths: {
          // paths serve as alias
          'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
          '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons',
          '@progress/kendo-angular-charts': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-charts',
          // our app is within the app folder
          app: 'app',
          // angular bundles
          '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
          '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
          '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
          '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
          '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
          '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
          '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
          '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
          // other libraries
          'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
          'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
          'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': {
               main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
               defaultExtension: 'js'
             },
          'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-charts': {
               main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
               defaultExtension: 'js'
             },
          app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
    })(this);
```

Now I get the following errors in the console:

> GET //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-popup 404 (Not Found) GET
>   //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor 404 (Not Found)
>   Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-popup(…) GET
>   //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-charts 404 (Not Found) GET
>   //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-intl 404 (Not Found) GET
>   //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-popup 404 (Not Found) GET
>   //localhost:3002/@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor 404 (Not Found)

So now I'm thinking I need to add more of these references/definitions to system.config.js.  So I did and now I have this:

```js
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons',
      '@progress/kendo-angular-charts': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-charts',
      '@progress/kendo-charts': 'npm:@progress/kendo-charts',
      '@progress/kendo-angular-popup': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-popup',
      '@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor',
      '@progress/kendo-angular-intl': 'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-intl',
      '@progress/kendo-popup-common': 'npm:@progress/kendo-popup-common',
      '@progress/kendo-drawing': 'npm:@progress/kendo-drawing',
      '@telerik/kendo-intl': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-intl',
      '@telerik/kendo-draggable': 'npm:@telerik/kendo-draggable',
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-buttons': {
           main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
           defaultExtension: 'js'
         },
      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-charts': {
           main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
           defaultExtension: 'js'
         },
      'npm:@progress/kendo-angular-resize-sensor': {
           main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
           defaultExtension: 'js'
         },
      'npm:@progress/kendo-charts': {
           main: './dist/npm/js/main.js',
           defaultExtension: 'js'
         },
      '@progress/kendo-angular-popup': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: "./dist/npm/js/main.js"
      },
      '@progress/kendo-angular-intl': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: "./dist/npm/js/main.js"
      },
      '@progress/kendo-popup-common': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: "./dist/npm/js/main.js"
      },
      '@progress/kendo-drawing': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: "./dist/npm/js/main.js"
      },
      '@telerik/kendo-intl': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: "./dist/npm/js/main.js"
      },
      '@telerik/kendo-draggable': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: "./dist/npm/js/main.js"
      },
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Now I get The following error:

> GET //localhost:3002/chroma-js 404 (Not Found) Error: (SystemJS)
>   XHR error (404 Not Found) loading //localhost:3002/chroma-js(…)
>   GET //localhost:3002/chroma-js 404 (Not Found)

Not sure what to do now. I'll try and post as much about my environment as possible. Any help is greatly appreciated.

node: version v.2.2
nmp: version 3.9.5
Kendo Charts:
[ '0.4.0',
  '0.4.1',
  '0.5.0',
  '0.5.1',
  '0.5.2',
  '0.5.3',
  '0.6.0',
  '0.7.0',
  '0.7.1',
  '0.7.2',
  '0.7.3',
  '0.7.4',
  '0.7.5',
  '0.8.0',
  '0.8.1' ]

App.moddule.ts

```js
     import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
     import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';      
     import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
     import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
     import { ChartsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';     

     import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

     @NgModule({
       declarations: [        
           AppComponent       
               ],        
         imports: [     
           BrowserModule,
           HttpModule,       
           ButtonsModule,
           ChartsModule        
           ],       
         providers: [],     
         bootstrap: [AppComponent]
     })
     export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```js
     import { Component } from '@angular/core';

     @Component({
       selector: 'my-app',
       styleUrls: [
         // load the default theme
         '../node_modules/@telerik/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css'
       ],       
       template: `
         My First Kendo UI Angular 2 App
         <button
           kendoButton
           (click)="onButtonClick()"
           [primary]="true">
           My Kendo UI Button
         </button>
       `
     })
     export class AppComponent {
       onButtonClick() {
         alert('Hello from Kendo UI!');
       }
     }
```

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^0.13.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^0.8.1",
    "@telerik/kendo-theme-default": "^1.29.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules//@telerik/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm also having problems:  Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…) when trying to add the charts.

Comment: Yes, the marked answer below allowed me to load the charts module.  The next hurdle, will be actually trying to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I had a similar issue,
In my case it had to do with chroma-js not being loaded.

Add this to your system.config.js:

map:

```
'chroma-js':'npm:chroma-js',
```

and in the packages:

```
'npm:chroma-js': {
          defaultExtension: 'js',
          main: "./chroma.js"
        },
```

After adding this this solved my issue.